# How and where to make the Retrofit call?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm a beginner Android developer trying to learn mobile development by building a movie database app.  I am writing my app in Kotlin and using Retrofit for the networking call.  I'm stuck on how and where to make the call to populate the Recyclerview with movie posters from the tmdb API.

This is my interface:

```
interface APImovies {
    fun getMovies()
}
```

This is my mainactivity with my Retrofit server object:

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        recyclerView.adapter = PosterAdapter()
    }

    object RetrofitServer{
        val client: APImovies by lazy{
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
            val retrofit = Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build()
            retrofit.create(APImovies::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my adapter that currently populates the Recyclerview with a placeholder image:

```
class PosterAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return 300}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PosterHolder{
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return PosterHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.movie_poster?.setImageResource(R.mipmap.beauty_and_the_beast_ver3)
        holder.view.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
    }
}

class PosterHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    var imageView: ImageView? = null

    fun PosterHolder(view: View){ this.imageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.movie_poster) as ImageView }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following setup. See if this could help you.

```
interface WebService {

    @GET
    fun getMovies(): Call<List<MyResponseObject>>

    companion object {
        fun create(): WebService {
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("YOUR_BASE_URL")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(WebService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity` do the following to do network call

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val webService = WebService.create()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: 
    PersistableBundle?) {
        /*...*/
        fetchMovies()
    }

    private fun fetchMovies() {
        var call = webService.getMovies()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<MyResponseObject> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyResponseObject>?, t: Throwable?) { }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyResponseObject>?, response: Response<List<Class>>?) {
                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
                    val myListData: MyResponseObject = response.body()
                    setUpRecyclerView(myListData) // The usual way of setting up a RecyclerView
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is only beginner friendly. I would recommend you to look into MVVM architecture using Android Architecture Components and Dagger 2 (For dependency injection). Since you use Kotlin you can take advantage by using [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html), [AndroidKTX](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-ktx-for-android-13a369795b51) and [Kodein](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI) for DI as said by **Nail Shaykhraziev**

Comment: Thank you.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you also give me an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

I use some like this:

```
public final class ApiClient {

private static OkHttpClient sClient;
private static volatile MovieService movieService;

private ApiClient() {
}

public static MovieService getMovieService() {
    MovieService service = movieService;
    if (service == null) {
        synchronized (ApiClient.class) {
            service = movieService;
            if (service == null) {
                service = movieService = buildRetrofit().create(MovieService.class);
            }
        }
    }
    return service; // this is one of the implementation options singlton pattern. You can use some di tools(Kodein, Dagger)
}

private static Retrofit buildRetrofit() {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(getClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

private static Gson getGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
}

private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = sClient;
    if (client == null) {
        synchronized (ApiClient.class) {
            client = sClient;
            if (client == null) {
                client = sClient = buildClient();
            }
        }
    }
    return client;
}

private static OkHttpClient buildClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(TokenInterceptor.create())
            .build();
}}
```

After in your Presenter/Interactor/ViewModel call retrofit service method:

```
ApiClient.movieService.popularMovies()
                .map { it.movies }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe { view.showProgress }
                .doAfterTerminate { view.hideProgress }
                .subscribeBy(onSuccess = {
                   view.showMovies(it)
                }, onError = {
                   view.showErrors()
                })
```

On Activity/Fragment/View :

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), MovieView {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      // your code
   }

  override fun showMovies(list: List<Movie>) {
     adapter.update(list)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I gave you an upvote out of appreciation. If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?